# Update tableView data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView embedded in a UIView that I can't figure out how to update.  When I come to this page with the UITableView embedded in the UIView there's a button that when pressed brings up a modalForm.  There is a textField that the user enters a name into and then presses another button to "Create" the object, dismiss the modalForm, and update the app data.  However, I'm not sure how to refresh my UITableView data… Is there a way to tell the UITableView to refresh when the modalForm view is dismissed?

EDIT:  I know i need to send this message `[tableView reloadData];` in order to refresh, but I'm wondering where I can put it so it gets called upon dismissal of the modalForm?

Comment: [`-[UITableView reloadData]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData)? Or KVC, but that's a more advanced topic.

Comment: Are you still working on this? Figure it out?

Comment: Not yet.  I've temporarily solved the issue by just pushing a view controller on the navigation stack instead of doing a modal transition, but I'd still like to be able to do modal presentation if possible…

Comment: Ok so what are missing to do the modal presentation route? Is there something missing from the answers below? If you comment on my question below with precisely what you need or don't get, I can edit my answer to further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view controller that is presenting and dismissing the modal, you should be calling the  `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` method to dismiss the modal. The modal should not dismiss itself. You can use a completion block to execute whatever code you would like that will execute when the modal is finished dismissing. Example below.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    //this code here will execute when modal is done being dismissed
    [_tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Of course don't forget to avoid capturing self strongly in the block.

If you end up having the modal dismiss itself, you will need either a delegate method so the modal can communicate back to the presenting view controller, or a notification sent by the modal and captured by the presenting view controller, or you could implement `viewWillAppear:` in the presenting view controller. This method will fire everytime the view is about to appear. Which means the very first time as well as after a modal is dismissed and is about to show the view it was presenting over top of.

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Below is an example of writing your own protocol and using it.

MyModalViewController.h

```
@protocol MyModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

//if you don't need to send any data
- (void)myModalDidFinishDismissing;

//if you need to send data
- (void)myModalDidFinishDismissingWithData:(YourType *)yourData

@end

@interface MyModalViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak) id <MyModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

//place the rest of your properties and public methods here

@end
```

The where ever you want to in your MyModalViewController implementation file, call your delegate method of choice. You should first make sure your delegate actually responds to the selector though.
MyModalViewController.m
    if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myModalDidFinishDismissing)] )
            [self.delegate myModalDidFinishDismissing];

In your viewcontroller that is presenting the modal, you need to state in the header file that you conform to the protocol, you need to set the delegate of the modal as the viewcontroller, and make sure you actually implement the delegate method you intend on using.

MyPresentingViewController.h

```
@interface MyPresentingViewController : UIViewController <MyModalViewControllerDelegate>
```

MyPresentingViewController.m

```
myModal.delegate = self;
- (void)myModalDidFinishDismissing {
    //do something
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What protocol should the presenting view controller adopt to be able to delegate?

Comment: And also, reading the documentation, I was under the impression viewWillAppear does NOT get called when returning from a presentedViewController? Or at least not a modal one?

Comment: If you are going to adopt a delegate in the presenting vc you will need to create that protocol in the vc you create that is being presented. I was unsure about the viewWillAppear piece so I actually tested it out locally before answering. Put a break point in viewWillAppear and it tripped when I dismissed a presented (modal) vc.

Comment: What protocol should the presenting view controller adopt?

Comment: When you create the viewcontroller class that will act as your modal you define a protocol in the header file (.h). The the presenting vc would act as the delegate of the modal vc and will respond to methods declared in its protocol.

Comment: I understand that.  I do not however know which protocol to use.  For example, when I have a UITableView, the delegate vc implements the <UITableViewDataSource> and <UITableViewDelegate> protocols...

Comment: You have to create your own protocol. See the edited answer above for how to do this. You should also consult this for a deeper understand https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: It worked!  Delegating was the key.  I appreciate your help especially as I've been slow to reply and implement your suggestions…

Answer (score 1):

You can have a delegate variable in your modal form class.  When you dismiss your modal form, you can call something like [delegate performSelector:@selector(modalFormClosed)] which calls the [tableView reloadData].

```
@interface ModalForm : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
@end

@implementation ModalForm
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(modalFormClosed)];
}
@end
```

In your class that uses the ModalForm:

```
myModalForm.delegate = self;
```

And make sure you have the modalFormClosed method too:

```
- (void)modalFormClosed {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Or you can send a NSNotification (look into NSNotificationCenter) when your modal form disappears.

Comment: When I try to implement this, I run into a problem of not being able to "identity" the presenting view controller.  In fact, when I NSLog the value of the presentingViewController of my modalForm, it logs NULL.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to paste your code in the question. Your presented vc should certainly know who is presenting it.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had the reference, but some years ago I saw a note from Apple saying a modal view should never dismiss itself.  Instead you call a method on a presenting view controller.  In this method the presenter dismisses the modal view controller.  Typically I put a category on my UIViewControllers:

```
@interface UIViewController (Extension)
-(void)simpleDismissAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
@end
@implementation UIViewController (Extension)
-(void)simpleDismissAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:nil];
}
```

Either include it in all your view controller subclasses, or in your pch file.

So have your modal view controller call:

```
[self.presentingViewController simpleDismissAnimated:YES];
```

Then in your presenting view controller, override the implementation of simpleDismissAnimated: to something like:

```
-(void)simpleDismissAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
[_tableView reloadData];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:nil;
}
```

That should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I'm wondering how I would call that line once I dismiss the modalForm?  Is there a method that gets called when I dismiss the modalForm?

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting `[tableView reloadData]` in viewWillAppear method where your tableView is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. ReloadData didn't work me. I solved it so that i made new method like this:

```
- (void)insertNewString:(NSString *)text{
        if (!_yourArrayWithData) {
            _yourArrayWithData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [_yourArrayWithData insertObject:text atIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
```

and when i want to add something to tableView, i use button with action like this:

```
- (IBAction)SaveNewPhrase:(id)sender {        
NSString *mainText = _NewPhraseTextView.text;   //I take nsstring from textView

if([mainText isEqual:@""]){
    return;
}else{
    NSMutableArray *contentFile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:docPathContents()];
    NSMutableArray *copyContentFile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

          //save array with new item        
    [copyContentFile addObject:mainText];
    [copyContentFile addObjectsFromArray:contentFile];
    [copyContentFile writeToFile:docPathContents() atomically:YES];   

    [self insertNewString:mainText];      //refresh tableView

    [_NewPhraseTextView resignFirstResponder];
}}
```

I hope, that it helps.